# Where to find the Dell Display Firmware Updater?

Tags: windows, display, firmware

I was having an issue with a Dell S3221QS monitor in Windows 11 on a new Lenovo X1 laptop. So I went looking to see if there are firmware updates. I found an [update](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/dell-s3221qs-monitor/drivers), granted it doesn't look like it will fix my problem but I wanted to try it. The download only seems to have the data file for the firmware update though, and not the utility to apply it with.

I found a [page](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000131809/steps-for-updating-the-firmware-for-your-dell-monitor) that describes the process of using a Display Firmware Updater, but it doesn't say were to download it from. I have looked all over and I can't find it. Can someone help point me to where I can get the updater? My Google-fu is failing me.

This is what is in the update zip file. I would expect there to be an installation application.
[image]

I searched folder structure for executables too.
[image]

---

Edit: 2022-10-17

It turns out that Dell apparently tried to do something a little to sophisticated and thought my computer was a Mac at first. This is the first zip file I downloaded.

Root of the zip
[image]

Main folder of the zip
[image]

When I downloaded from the very same link a second time I got the Windows executable in the zip file. Note the M vs W in the zip file name.

Root of the zip file the second time
[image]

Main folder of the second zip download
[image]

These were all downloaded using the same laptop.

Comment: What do the instructions have to say about it? I wouldn't expect an installation process for a firmware, I would expect there to be an executable, which run and performs the task.  The installation of a program seems overkill for a one use program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update named "Dell S3221QS Monitor Firmware Update" in your link
is a zip file containing an `.exe` file and a PDF with instructions.

This looks like what you are looking for.

If you get any warning messages from the application, don't force it.

Comment: I updated the post to show what is in the zip. I would also expect there to be an executable in there.

Comment: This isn't the same file as I downloaded. I refer to the optional download that contains `Dell_MonitorFirmwareUpdateUtility_W_S3221QS_M2C103.exe` and `Firmware_Update_Instruction.pdf`.

Comment: See my additions this morning

Comment: Do the instructions and `.exe` work for you ?

Comment: I haven't tried the exe in the second download yet, but I will let you know

Comment: The update worked